# Hazelcast Jet after rollingAggregate how to get each grouped values in one go only?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet, hazelcast-aggregate

I am trying to to do the aggregation on the data but I am trying rollingAggregate but as it's streaming process it processes asyn but my need is I need to do sum of amount and group by id and country.

Here is my below code:

```
BatchStage<Object> list= // coming from jdbc

list.groupingKey( data -> {
  // grouping ke logic for ID, Country
}.rollingAggregate(AggregateOperations.toList()).
map(entry -> {

      if (((Entry<String, List<Object>>)entry).getKey().equals("36465,Indonesia")) {
        **//Here for this ID and Country it is coming twice with different records but for each grouping key I want it just once only.**
      }         

     List<Object> resultRow = new ArrayList<>();
     ((Entry<String, List<Object>>)entry).getValue().stream().forEach(data -> {
     
      });
      return resultRow;
});
```

Data (Here I am getting data from Jdbc source):

```
[['id','country','id2','amount']
 [3638, Dominican Republic, 'Qee', 973029], 
 [3638, Dominican Republic, 'Hee', 95571], 
 [3668, USA, 'Fee', 986839], 
 [3668, USA, 'CEE', 201017]]
```

Result Needed (But as I have millions records do not want to group in one go):

```
[['id','country','id2','amount']
 [3638, Dominican Republic, 1068600],  
 [3668, USA,1187856]]
```

And I am doing grouping by id and country columns.

And in grouping by key comes two time in map:

First time getting:

```
{"3638,Dominican Republic" : [[3638, Dominican Republic, 'Hee', 95571]]}
```

Second time getting:

```
{"3638,Dominican Republic" : [[3638, Dominican Republic, 'Qee', 973029]]}
```

But need it one go only (**May be because using Jdbc source which sends data in Batchstage?**):

```
{"3638,Dominican Republic" : [[3638, Dominican Republic, 'Qee', 973029], 
 [3638, Dominican Republic, 'Hee', 95571]]}
```

So Could anyone help how for each grouping key wise we get all the records in one go only but I don't want all the grouping key in one go?

Comment: Maybe add some sample data which demonstrates what you want to get.

Comment: @FrantišekHartman I have added requirement and example.

Answer (score 0):

The `rollingAggregate` outputs the result of each aggregation for each input item, see the [JavaDoc](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/pipeline/GeneralStage.html#rollingAggregate-com.hazelcast.jet.aggregate.AggregateOperation1-).

So what you should see is the following:

```
3638,Dominican Republic=[Item[id=3638, country=Dominican Republic, id2=Qee, amount=973029]]
3638,Dominican Republic=[Item[id=3638, country=Dominican Republic, id2=Qee, amount=973029], Item[id=3638, country=Dominican Republic, id2=Hee, amount=95571]]
3668,USA=[Item[id=3668, country=USA, id2=Fee, amount=986839]]
3668,USA=[Item[id=3668, country=USA, id2=Fee, amount=986839], Item[id=3668, country=USA, id2=Cee, amount=201017]]
```

First you receive the key with 1 item, than 2 items etc.. If you only see one item at a time, your group function is probably wrong.

If you don't want the intermediate results, but only final aggregation with all items, you should just use `aggregate` instead:

```
3668,USA=[Item[id=3668, country=USA, id2=Fee, amount=986839], Item[id=3668, country=USA, id2=Cee, amount=201017]]
3638,Dominican Republic=[Item[id=3638, country=Dominican Republic, id2=Qee, amount=973029], Item[id=3638, country=Dominican Republic, id2=Hee, amount=95571]]
```

which is produced by the following code:

```
public record Item(int id, String country, String id2, int amount) implements Serializable {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    p.readFrom(TestSources.items(
             new Item(3638, "Dominican Republic", "Qee", 973029),
             new Item(3638, "Dominican Republic", "Hee", 95571),
             new Item(3668, "USA", "Fee", 986839),
             new Item(3668, "USA", "Cee", 201017)
     )).groupingKey(item -> item.id + "," + item.country)
     .aggregate(AggregateOperations.toList())
     .writeTo(Sinks.logger());

    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.bootstrappedInstance();
    hz.getJet().newJob(p).join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but here it is one problem I think first groupingKey will loop though whole data and group them and then it will send further one by one if I am not wrong.

Comment: You must process all data to produce the aggregation, otherwise if you did it e.g. in batches using some kind of windowing you would get only subset of the items for each key, but you state you need all items in one go.

Comment: Yes I got your point your correct but what happens when there huge data let's say around 5 lakh records it takes time to group it so I have to reduce that time some how. For that can we do something, any suggetions?